# Pair and curly brace check

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
  pair<int,int>p = {1,3};

  if (p=={1,3})
      cout << "yeyey\n";

}
```

I want to check whether this pair is same as the integer inside the braces, but it returns error

```
"expected unqualified-id before ')' token if (p=={1,3}) cout << "yeyey\n";"
```

can someone explain why?

Comment: Warning: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` [loads the gun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). `using namespace std;` [takes off the safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). After that, [it's really easy for the program to shoot itself](https://godbolt.org/z/6sWGov). Use with caution, but prefer to not use at all.

Comment: omg people stop using bits/stdc++.h!!!

Comment: mostly used for short example code or in competetive programming if you need to write really fast

Comment: @Yamahari -- With the advent of C++ 17, having that `bits` header, plus `using namespace std;` will lead to *very strange* errors if the program uses a variable called [data](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data).  Note that `data` isn't the only name that will cause these issues.  All of that time "competing" will now be spent scratching heads as to why the program doesn't compile.

Comment: sorry, but I used those bits/stdc++ for competitive programming, btw thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `{1,3}` cannot be used to deduce a `std::pair<K,T>` directly. You'll need to use `std::make_pair()` to overcome this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    
  std::pair<int,int>p = {1,3};

  if (p==std::make_pair(1,3))
      std::cout << "yeyey\n";    
}
```

Since c++17 you can alternatively use a temporary with a direct initializer for  `std::pair<T,K>`:

```
  if (p==std::pair{1,3})
```

See a online demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/894ba424c8ba025b).

Comment: thanks for your comment! I understand what the cause now.

Answer (score 1):

The way the language works `{1, 3}` in that context cannot be resolved to a type so you need:

```
// since c++17
p == std::pair{1, 3}

// before
p == std::make_pair(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the operator `==` you need to compare two pairs, but `{1,3}` is not a pair. To do so you need to `cast` the object into a pair. Just like you would cast an integer to a float `float f = (float)123`. therefor the correct way to do so is this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    pair<int, int> p = { 1, 3 };
    if (p == (pair<int,int>{1, 3}))
        cout << "yay!" << endl;
}
```

Also please note that specifying `using namespace std;` is a bad habit and should not be used.

Comment: Note: `if (p == (pair<int,int>{1, 3}))` didn't cast. It created a temporary `pair` to compare against. This is the right solution, but casting plays no part in it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am no expert in STL still can tell, you cannot initialize a pair like that. You have to either call its parameterized constructor or `make_pair()` function template.

```
pair <int , int> p(1, 3);    //constructor one
pair <int , int> p = make_pair(1, 3);    // function template
```

Of course can do this.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
  pair<int,int>p;
  p = {1,3}; // This here is actually the overloaded assignment operator which is copying
}
```

Also you can not compare your pair with {1, 3} Use:

```
if(p == make_pair(1,3)) // this 
if (p.first == 1 && p.second == 3) // or this
```

You should read documentation for if you want to know some internal structure because I am not much aware of it.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't put `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` in an answer and avoid putting `using namespace std;` in an answer. Both have bad effects individually and together they can combine to form a program-destroying megazord. Basically, it's stuff you don't leave lying around where some kid could find it.

Comment: I will take care next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use init-statement in if + structured bindings to do this in C++17:

```cpp
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::pair<int, int> p{1, 2};
    if(auto &[x0, x1] = p; x0 == 1 && x1 == 2)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```